# iOS 9 disable support for right-to-left language

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

My iOS app is in Arabic (right-to-left) language only. Prior to iOS 9 the views layout and view animations were all by default left-to-right. So, I had customised the complete app and had reversed the default behaviour e.g. back button in navigation bar was set to be on the right instead of default left.

But now when the app is compiled using latest SDK (Xcode 7 beta 4), everything is the opposite of what I need.

Is there any simple way to force the app to show views and behave like iOS 8 and 7?

I searched and found a solution but it involves changing the constraints(Uncheck the "Respect language direction") for all views. But this is not a feasible solution in large projects.

This is a screenshot after compiling with Xcode 7 beta 4.
[image: .]

and this is a screenshot when compiled with Xcode 6.
[image]

Comment: have you tried the answers in the post?

Answer (score 22):

Edit: The following code may cause unexpected behavior as @wakachamo pointed out. So, please watch out for issues e.g. Interactive pop gesture doesn't work, alertviews don't show, etc. Its better to follow the instruction provided by @wakachamo if this doesn't work for you

Add this to app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
[[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
```

Also add guard to support earlier version so that the property doesn't cause any crash.

```
if([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    }
```

[[UIView alloc] init] instead of [UIView appearance] because respondsToSelector is not currently working with [UIView appearance] for setSemanticContentAttribute. You can also add iOS 9 Check

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    }
```

Comment: This is not a supported configuration and will lead to several bugs and inconsistencies in your app.

Comment: Yes it may be the case, but it is the only thing that works till now for navigationcontrollers, to make them left to right, as far as I know. For individual items semanticContentAttribute works best as you described.

Comment: Thanks guys! I had found a more simple solution for my case. Please see my answer.

Comment: I had to add this string: '        [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:NSClassFromString(@"_UIAlertControllerView"), nil] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeUnspecified];
' Otherwise actionSheets won't display any buttons except for cancel button.

Comment: Regarding navigation controllers, setting the semanticContentAttribute on UINavigationController.view should do the right thing.

Comment: @AbdullahUmer where's ur answer.. add url

Answer (score 16):

i found the correct way from Apple Developer Forums

here [iOS 9 beta - UIAlertController is not working](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12775)

just add this code to make alertview work with it

```
 if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];

    [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeUnspecified];
    [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertView class], nil] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeUnspecified];



}
```

Comment: It does not work properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932463/rtl-language-behavior-in-ios-9

Answer (score 13):

I know its too late to answer. But I have figured it out (Only the navigation bar issue).

The answer is adapted from @Kamran Kan. Thanks @Kamran.

Jus replace the **UIView** with **UINavigationBar** in @Kamran's answer. then the code will be as follows.

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
}
```

Since it is only effect the UINavigationBar, the other controls won't effect. So the UIAlertView is working fine...

Comment: perfect answer for nav bar

Comment: Thanks, this answer works for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736141/position-of-navigation-buttons-in-rtl-languages-are-not-correct-in-ipad?noredirect=1#comment78460346_45736141

Answer (score 7):

There is no easy way. It's recommended that you migrate to standard API as much as possible long-term.

Another approach is to set the `semanticContentAttribute` of all the affected views to `UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight`, but this is just as feasible as setting all your constraints to use Left/Right instead of Leading/Trailing. In addition to this, you'll also have to gate these calls around an availability check if you're targeting iOS <9.

Comment: i am having a problem in the UITextField placeholder. it is still showing from right to left. I tried to alter the: 
 UITextField.appearance(). semanticContentAttribute

and 

UITextField.appearance().UITextField.appearance().makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(nil) 

but useless

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 2** Code

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
     myView.semanticContentAttribute = .ForceLeftToRight
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For **SWIFT 3**

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
     UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Storyboard and choose for each specific view controllers

Semantic->Force Left-to-Right.

[image: Force Left-to-Right]