# RTL language behavior in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Our app supports RTL language like Arabic, Persian.

After  iOS 9 the navigation controller and tab bar controller behavior has been changed. I found only this link [ios-9-disable-support-for-right-to-left-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697426/ios-9-disable-support-for-right-to-left-language) for solve this problem

I write this code in my `appDelegate` and it works fine and navigation bar and tab bar set as LTR.

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
}
```

But **my problem is:
I can't change interactive pop gesture Direction .**

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Fogmeister  because it's has a bad style and not regular for UX . you can change Language and see Whatsapp   ( they have handled this problem ) but telegram team leave this problem.
Do u have any idea ?

Comment: Is that your opinion or is it something you have spoken to many rtl users about? Where I work we spent a long time interviewing our users. It really is something that rtl users want.

Comment: @Fogmeister i'm agree with you , but in this case we need this and in Apple Docs you can see this :
~Flipping Cocoa Touch Views and Controls Programmatically`
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Comment: Mohamad, that doc only describes ways to adapt controls to the new RTL UI in iOS 9, which is the opposite of what you are trying to do here. I would highly recommend not doing this; as more apps start linking against iOS 9, more apps will have the flipped UI by default if they support a RTL language. At the end of the day, it will be your app that will be inconsistent with the rest of the system.

Comment: @wakachamo thanks my Bro for your hint

Comment: I have the same issue, I just try to disable it and not find any other solution, if you found out please publish it, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32097310/3477974

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard i recommend to you leave this behavior. because it's normal and all of apps in app store accept this behavior :)

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with same problem and finally found solution

you just need to set SemanticContentAttribute for navigationController.view

in the rootViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
[self.navigationController.view setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift

```
navigationController?.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
navigationController?.navigationBar.semanticContentAttribute =  .forceRightToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are creating custom pop up, two way you can handle this.

1. Define a macro in .h file to detect whether it is RTL language or not in runtime.

   define IS_RTL [UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft

then create custom layout according if IS_RTL.Like

```
if (IS_RTL)
//Do Arabic Implementation
else
//Do other language implementation
```

2. If you are creating UI from Storyboard, the set constraint to Lead or Trailing space and value of First Item will be **Respect Language Direction**

Comment: tnx for your  answer , but unfortunately  after i OS 9 we cant do it without `setSemanticContentAttribute` anyway , `Respect Language Direction` is good for our alignment  but for our direction not work.
conclusion  :  we respect to this behavior like many app to app store :)