# Position of navigation buttons in RTL languages are not correct in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar, right-to-left

Position of navigation buttons in RTL languages are not correct in iPad

Position of navigation button in iPad and iPhone is different when device language is set to Arabic (RTL)

Could anyone please guide why this is happening and how to fix this?
Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Below are the screenshot and details of the device:

**1. RTL_iPad_Retina_iOS8.4** (device having incorrect position of buttons)

`Device: iPad Retina
OS: iOS 8.4`

[image]

**2. RTL_iPhone_6sPlus_iOS10.2**

`Device: iPhone 6s plus
OS: iOS 10.2`

[image]

Comment: Do you use the same code and/or xibs for the two sizes? Is there any possible variation between them?

Comment: Same xibs. Using xibs with auto layout.

Double checked my app on iPad with iOS version 9 and above and it works fine.
But this issue is with iPad iOS 8.x devices only.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the bottom bar with the text input is behaving like expected both on iPhone and iPad, correct?

Comment: My question is about the position of buttons on navigations bar. Bottom bar issue is known to me

Comment: What I am trying to understand is that if it's only the navigation bar that doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: This looks like an iOS 8.4 iPad device issue. I can see the incorrect position of back button on all the screens.

Additionally, I can see that iPad main menu (where we see all the apps) is not changing to RTL (I have to swipe right to see apps, whereas in iPhone in case of RTL swipe changes from RTL as well)

Answer (score -2):

*You Can Modify With CSS If You Are Using ion-buttons left
Just Change Your Button Order*

```
.bar-buttons[left] {
            @include ltr(){
                -webkit-order: 2;
                -ms-flex-order: 2;
                order: 2;
            }
            @include rtl(){
                -webkit-order: 5;
                -ms-flex-order: 5;
                order: 5;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, extend you answer with explanation. It will be useful for users with different levels of understanding. Thank you!